# How to change a call with Reverse engineering

Tags: windows, dll, assembly, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I have an example program `test1.exe` that uses an example library `test2.dll`.

- `test.dll` contains the functions `A()` and `B()` of the same type.
- `test1.exe` calls `A` and then exits.

Here I've found the call to `A()`:
[image: The line which test.exe calls A]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W9Jd.jpg)

Now, if i'm not mistaken, I need to replace `88FDFFFF` with the correct offset of `B()`, but how can I calculate it so that `B()` will be invoked instead of `A()`?

Comment: If you are going to work with binary debugging tools, you better make a serious investment in understanding the instruction set of your targeted computer.  This information is easily found in reference manuals; for the x86, Intel provides easily found online references that will drown you in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this in an x86 call-relative instruction, the offset value is computed by subtracting the address of the instruction following the call (= call instruction location + 5 bytes), from the address of the target.  So, you need to patch the offset to be address(B)-address(callinstruction+5).

Comment: Okay. But `B()` is located in a dll, so what exactly is `address(B)`? I know it's entry point inside `test2.dll`, but how to translate it to an address in `text1.exe`? And does `callinstruction+5 = ADD ESP,0C`?

Comment: Welcome to reverse engineering, where you get to learn more about system details than you really want to know.  Time for you to learn how DLLs are organized, and how a function in a DLL is invoked by standard code.   Then you'll understand how to find the address(A), and therefore the address(B).   [I wouldn't write "callinstruction+5 = ADD..." as a sensible equation.  I didn't check your example to see what instruction follows the call; it may be that specific ADD is that instruction.  In that case, "address(callinstruction)+5 == address(ADD ...)" if that was your question]

Answer (score 0):

if `b` is imported in test1.exe it is easy otherwise you have to use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress.

press `ctrl+N` to see if `b` is imported or not.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to learn asm basics first and play with HIEW hexeditor/disassembler to change simple codes.

Comment: I know asm, and HIEW is not comfortable to use.

Comment: Yeah right, HIEW is the basic tool for 99.9% of reversers, get used to it, it's pretty easy to use.

Comment: Most reversers use IDA and OllyDBG. I do it for a living and have never used HIEW. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: So when you have to modify the binary how do you do it? From IDA's hex view? If you never had to use HIEW I'm sorry but you are half-way reverse engineer and maybe you never had more challenging projects to do. Just my 14 years of experience.